# plotly stacked bar graph showing negative value as positive

Tags: r, plotly

Here is the dataframe, with the 2nd row being 1.41 & - 1.40
[image]

However, when I use plotly, the graph did not show the negative value on chart.[image][image]

Here's my code, how do I make the graph to show the negative on chart?

```
fig <- plot_ly(delay, x = ~AIRLINE_NAME, y = ~dep_mean, type = 'bar',name = 'Departure_Delay')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~arr_mean, name = 'Arrival_Delay')
fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Minute'), xaxis = list(title = 'Airline Name'), barmode = 'stack')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mention in the `layout` that `barmode = "relative"`. This will also plot the negative values. I created a sample data from your dataset. You can use this code:

```
delay <- data.frame(AIRLINE = c("AA", "AS", "B6", "DL", "EV", "F9", "HA", "MQ", "NK", "OO"),
                 dep_mean = c(8.4, 1.4, 12, 6.6, 8.4, 12.6, 0.6, 9.9, 16.7, 7.5),
                 arr_mean = c(3.0, -1.4, 7.4, -0.7, 6.2, 11.5, 1.5, 6.3, 15.3, 5.4),
                 AIRLINE_NAME = c("American Airlines Inc", "Alaska Airlines Inc", "JetBlue Airways", "Delta Air lines Inc", "Atlantic Southeast Airlines", "Frontier Airlines Inc", "Hawaiian airlines", "American Eagle Arilines inc", "Spirit Air lines", "Skywest Airlines inc"))

library(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(delay, x = ~AIRLINE_NAME, y = ~dep_mean, type = 'bar',name = 'Departure_Delay')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~arr_mean, name = 'Arrival_Delay')
fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Minute'), xaxis = list(title = 'Airline Name'), barmode = 'relative')

fig
```

Output fig:

[image]